# Is the majority of potential energy converted to heat or sound during collision between a coin and a glass surface?

Tags: energy-conservation

When a coin is dropped from a certain height and collides with a glass surface, is the majority of the potential energy converted to sound or heat? And how would one determine this as I only hear the sound and cannot measure the significant change in temperature? (assuming elastic)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by the final "assuming elastic" in this. Elastic means that it bounces back with all its energy.

Strictly speaking, it all becomes heat eventually. Also strictly speaking, this is not fully defined. It is a question of the materials and nature of fall and impact. For example, if the table is perfectly elastic, so that the coin bounces back with all its energy, it will still come to a stop after a number of cycles due to air resistance. In this case, the air resistance is converting the motion to heat (eventually), and while the coin is bouncing up and down, it is making *some* sound in the air.

When the coin impacts the table, both the table and coin vibrate. These vibrations *are* the sound of the impact. There also will be sound due to the air between the coin and table being squeezed out as the impact happens. Some of the vibration energy leaves the table and coin and enters the air as sound to bounce around the room until it becomes thermal energy. Other vibration energy dies out and converts to thermal energy directly in the vibrating solid itself due to its internal resistance (hysteresis).

Even if you fully defined the problem, a solution is unlikely past the most high level assumptions. You would likely need to do a numerical simulation.